# mysql query - multiple counts using left join and where clause

Tags: mysql, database, relationship, where-clause

I'm currently trying to get the following data:

UserName, UserImageURL, Total Games Played, Games Completed, Games Lost, Average Won (as percentage) and Points of the user

And as well another set of data:

User Statistics data such as:

- Most Games Played on League: 23 - Monster Killers
- Games Most Won On: 19/23 - Monster Killers
- Games Most Lost On: 3/32 - Frog Racers
- Your Game Winning Accuracy (total from all games) - 68% accuracy

Site Stats:

- Most Games Played on League: 650 - Helicopter Run
- Top Game Played: 1200 - Monster Killers
- Whole site winning accuracy: 82%

I have the following Tables:

-User Table-

userID (int-pk), userName (varchar), userImageUrl (text)

-Games table-

gameId (int-pk), gameName (varchar), gameUserID (int), gameLeagueId (int), score1 (int), score2 (int), gameResultOut (0 or 1), gameWon (0 or 1)

-UserBalance table-

ubId(int-pk)    userId (int)      balance (int)

-League table-
leagueId (int-pk)  leagueName (varchar)

Just to give you a heads up on what's happening, when a user plays a game and chooses some results a row is inserted into the games table. Since the game is time based, when the results are out, there is a check that checks if there are any games which have that id and will update the gameResultOut to 1 and gameWon to 1 or 0 according to what the user had selected as a score.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT u.userID, u.userName, u.userImageUrl, l.leagueName , 
COUNT(g.gameId) AS predTotal, 
(SELECT COUNT(g.gameId) FROM games AS g WHERE g.gameResultOut = 1 AND g.gameWon = 1) AS gamesWon,
(SELECT COUNT(g.gameId) FROM games AS g WHERE g.gameResultOut = 1 AND g.gameWon = 0) AS gamesLost, 
ub.balance 
FROM games AS g
LEFT JOIN league AS l ON l.leagueId = g.gameLeagueId 
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = g.gameUserID 
LEFT JOIN user_balance AS ub ON ub.userId = u.userID 
WHERE l.leagueId = 4
GROUP BY u.userId 
ORDER BY ub.balance DESC
```

I can calculate easily the win percentage after the query so that's not a problem, but the result for the Wins and Lost are all the same and even when it comes to changing the leageId, the results are still the same which is not what I want.

Can anyone help?

Thanks & Regards,
Necron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, the *games* table stores games that *users* played. So, in order to know how many games **each user** played/won/lost, you're missing the link in the subqueries between *games* and *users*.

Your subqueries are:

```
(SELECT COUNT(g.gameId ) FROM games AS g WHERE g.gameResultOut = 1 AND g.gameWon = 1) AS gamesWon,
(SELECT COUNT(g.gameId) FROM games AS g WHERE g.gameResultOut = 1 AND g.gameWon = 0) AS gamesLost,
```

And they should be:

```
(SELECT COUNT(gw.gameId ) FROM games AS gw WHERE gw.gameResultOut = 1 AND gw.gameWon = 1 AND gw.gameUserID = u.user_id) AS gamesWon,
(SELECT COUNT(gl.gameId) FROM games AS gl WHERE gl.gameResultOut = 1 AND gl.gameWon = 0 AND gl.gameUserID = u.user_id) AS gamesLost,
```

I guess this is what you're looking for :)

---

**EDIT** based on comments, adding tips for User and Site statistics:

For those information you'll need to perform several distinct queries, as most of them are going to sum some values and/or group by a given column, which won't fit for another query. I'll try to give you some ideas so you can work on them.

## User Statistics

### Most Games Won or Lost

The previous answer for the query you provided counts how many *times* user has lost/won *any* game, but does not distinct this data between games.

So, if you want to know *in which* game user has most wins/losses, you should have something like this:

```
SELECT
    g.gameName,
    -- How many times the user won per game
    (SELECT COUNT(gw.gameId) FROM games gw WHERE gw.gameResultOut = 1 AND gw.gameWon = 1 AND  gw.gameUserID = u.user_id) AS gamesWon,
    -- How many times the user payed each game
    COUNT(g.gameId) AS gamesPlayed,
    -- The Win Ratio. This may need a little work on, depending on what you want.
    -- Be aware that if a user played a game 1 time and won, it's ratio will be 1 (100%)
    -- So maybe you'll want to add your own rule to determine which game should show up here
    (gamesWon / gamesPlayed) AS winRatio
FROM
    games g
    INNER JOIN user u ON u.user_id = g.gameUserID 
-- Groups and counts data based on games + users
GROUP BY g.gameId, u.user_id
-- Now you order by the win ratio
ORDER BY winRatio DESC
-- And get only the first result, which means the game the player has most wins.
LIMIT 1
```

For lost games, it's pretty much the same query, changing the desired fields and maths.

### Game winning accuracy

Somewhat the previous query, except that you won't group by the gameID anymore. Just group by the user and do your math.

## Site Statistics

Well, as far as I see, we're still on a similar query. The difference is that for the whole Site statistics you won't ever group by user. You may group by game or league, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

---

Bottom line: looks that most queries are similar, you'll have to play with them and adapt for each information you need to retrieve. **Please note that they might not work plenty** as I could not test them on your DB. You may need to correct some inconsistence according to your database/tables schema.

I hope this may give you some insight to work on.

Comment: Thank you mate, but it did not work perfectly, I don't know why it gets the same results for Lost / Amount of Games Won and Amount of games lost although other users now have different values :). What about the best approach to get the User and Site stats of the above? How can I formulate a single or two queries? I'm still learning mysql. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, I guess you'll need to make several  distinct queries to get all those information. See: with what I answered you, you may know how much games the user won among _all_ games, but you can't tell in which specific game it won most times. So this means it's another query just for that. I'll try to edit my answer and add some examples to show you the path ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. As regarding to the first query, worked perfectly thanks. Learned that I have to change the subquery AS  gw when I need to get unique data and that I still have to add the relation of the user and the game. I'll test the other queries and let you know. Will answer the question as correct when everything is fine :) Thank you for your assistance

Comment: I don't know why it's asking unknown column gamesWon. Doesn't it select the AS column?I don't know why it's asking unknown column gamesWon. Doesn't it select the AS column?

Comment: Maybe it's because there was a typo in the subquery, I was using `g.gameWon` instead of `gw.gameWon` (I already edited and fixed the query). If this is not the issue, post your whole query so I can take a look.

Comment: No that wasn't it, as I actually knew that there was a mistype ;/ (gamesPlayed / gamesWon) AS winRatio is the actual problem, the AS fields are not being read. If I remove this, and remove the order by, it works perfectly

Comment: SELECT gameName, FullName, gamesWon, gamesPlayed,(gamesWon / gamesPlayed) AS winRatio FROM (SELECT g.gameName AS gameName,
        u.full_name AS FullName,
        (SELECT COUNT(gw.game_id) FROM games gw WHERE gw.ResultOut= 1 AND gw.gameWon = 1 AND gw.game_userId = u.user_id) AS gamesWon, 
        COUNT(g.game_id) AS gamesPlayed
        FROM games g
        INNER JOIN useru ON u.user_id = g.game_id
        LEFT JOIN gameNames gn ON gn.game_id= g.game_id
GROUP BY u.user_id,g.game_id) t
ORDER BY winRatio DESC

I have removed the row for the game name and added a table named Game Names. Thanks!

Comment: @Necron I took a look and your query looks fine to me... But I could not test it as I do not have your schema to query on. I know for sure that you can `ORDER BY` an _alias_ (the "AS" we use), so I think it's more of a query logical problem. What is the exact error MySQL gives you?

Comment: No that query actually works :) Had to make an internal select, so that's actually the answer :) Thanks mate! Now in order to get the actual results, I just have to change the order by and sort ;)